# How to move database operations from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've started to work on old project with new tools. This time - Rails on Ruby. I managed to make some progress, and now i want to improve one element of my code.

Whole project is about bugtracking with full history search of all tracked bugs. Now i'm on stage where user is entering bugs. Every bug belong to table which belongs to projects.

Only problem - now - is autocompletion of table name when i'm using completely new name (with tables that are already present in database it's working just fine, fills table_id in Bug entry).

Part of view responsible for entering (or selecting from existing) table looks like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :table_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :table_name, autocomplete_table_name_bugs_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nothing unusual. This one goes to the model (Bug.rb)

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bugid, :fixdate, :fixnote, :fixstate_id, :milestone, :newtarget, :notes, :oldtarget, :project_id, :bugreason, :reason_id, :regressiondate, :regressionstate_id, :source, :stringid, :table_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :reason
  belongs_to :state

  def table_name
     table.name if table
  end

  #def table_name=(name)
  #  self.table = Table.find_or_create_by_name(name) unless name.blank?
  #end

end
```

No validation for now as you can see. table_name=(name) commented as it's apparently doing nothing in my code.

This is working with bugs controller (bugs_controller.rb)

```
def create
  if params[:bug][:table_id].nil?
    if Table.find_or_create_by_name(params[:bug][:table_name])
      params[:bug][:table_id] = Table.find_by_name(params[:bug][:table_name]).id
      params[:bug].delete :table_name
    end

  end

  @bug = Bug.new(params[:bug])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bug.save
      format.html { redirect_to bugs_path, notice: 'Bug was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @bug, status: :created, location: @bug }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @bug.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I put here only part responsible for saving new bugs, i'll manage to handle update part when i do this part right.

What i want to improve is first part. Now it's responsible not only for changing table_name to table_id but for creation of new table if it doesn't exist. I'm aware that this part should be handled by model, but i've no idea how to do that, could use some help.

Another part, as btw. is my dropdown menu where user can select active project. It's handled by partial:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <% if project.id == session[:current_project].to_i %>
        <li class="disabled"><%= link_to project.name, '#' %></li>
    <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to project.name, choose_project_path(project.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it works fine only when used from projects controller. How - by the book - i can handle this from other controllers? To be exact, i want it working same way in whole project.

For now i'm handling it by snippet in every controller, but i'm pretty sure that RoR gods are not happy with me for that.

```
  before_filter :projects

  def projects
    @projects = Project.all
  end
```

How it should be done in proper way? :)

Comment: now i see that maybe 'before_create' in model can do the work... but still, suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: Figured it out somehow. Will post answer tommorow - it went without before_create, but all logic is moved from controller to model - with almost same code as posted in question. Still one question left, but i'll post it as separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to move logic from controller to model. Also, it's saving all data i need - table_id to bugs table and project_id (stored in session) to tables table when creating new table.

So part of form render is not changed:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :table_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :table_name, autocomplete_table_name_bugs_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Model now looks like this:

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :table_name, :bugid, :fixdate, :fixnote, :fixstate_id, :milestone, :newtarget, :notes, :oldtarget, :project_id, :bugreason, :reason_id, :regressiondate, :regressionstate_id, :source, :stringid, :table_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :reason
  belongs_to :state

  def table_name
     table.name if table
  end

  def table_name=(name)
    self.table = Table.find_or_create_by_name(name, project_id: self.project_id ) unless name.blank?
  end

end
```

So only change is uncommenting table_name= method and adding project_id to creation of new table (and lack of project_id was the reason it didn't work earlier).

Controller looks like this:

```
  def create

    @bug = Bug.new(params[:bug])
    @bug.project_id = session[:current_project]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bug.save
        format.html { redirect_to bugs_path, notice: 'Bug was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @bug, status: :created, location: @bug }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @bug.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It's working like charm. Still i've question remaining, but will post it as separate one.